# repeat a function after user input

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote the following code to count digits in an integer and display the result (which it does).  I need to ask the user if they want to continue after the result is displayed (`1` for yes, `0` for no).  No matter what I have tried, it will not display the first answer and THEN ask if they (user) wants to enter another number.

```
def countDigits(n):
    return len(str(n))

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("The number of digits for:",num, "is:", countDigits(num))
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `while` loop.

```
def countDigits(n):
    return len(str(n))

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print("The number of digits for:",num, "is:", countDigits(num), flush=True)
    cont = input("Do you want to continue (1/0)?")
    if cont.strip() == '0':
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Daniele, but that did not work either.  It did not display the first answer until I answered the "Do you want to continue" question.  And FYI, the input from that question has to be a 1 or 0.

Comment: Now it should work. You just have to add `flush=True` at the end of the `print()` function.

Comment: I must be having an issue.  PyScripter won't print the number the first and then ask...Once I answer the question, it works (it prints the first answer and then quits when it's supposed to and continues as it's supposed to).  Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: So that must be a problem with `PyScripter`. Look at this: https://repl.it/repls/GleefulPrettyEvaluations

Comment: That must be it....Thanks so much for your help....I really appreciate it!!  Addio!!

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple while loop will do:

```
userAnswer = True    
while(userAnswer):
     num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
     print("The number of digits for:",num, "is:", countDigits(num))

     ans=int(input('Do Want to continue? 0=>no, 1=>yes: '))
     if ans==0:
          userAnswer = False
     elif ans==1:
          userAnswer = True
```

Comment: That worked too Sakib.  Using PyScripter doesn't show the answer first and THEN prompt the user for input.  But it works and that's all that's important!!